# How can I copy a user while preserving all privs?

Tags: sql-server-2008, users

We're changing domains.  I'd like to create a new account for myself, `NewDomain\Bob` which has the same su-level privileges as `OldDomain\Bob`, to minimize the chance of disruption when IT flips the switch.

I can easy assign the new login the same database roles.  However, I'd like to associate the new login with the same users.  Sadly, it seems that a user can have only one login.  So what are the alternatives?

I could create the new login with a temporary user, reassign ownership of schemas, drop the old dbo user, and finally rename the new user.  However, this would strip some privileges from the old login.  In practice this may not matter, but I don't like the idea of cutting off any of my own privs before the new account is available.

[The `sp_change_users_login` stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259633%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) looked promising to repoint the dbo user to the new login, but it has some serious limits - like not being usable with Windows logins.

Is there a workaround, or am I perhaps trying to fix the wrong problem?

Comment: This isn't a real solution to your problem, but are `ALTER USER DatabaseUserName WITH LOGIN = NewLoginName` or `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::DatabaseName TO NewLoginName` the sort of statements you're looking for instead of `sp_change_users_login`?

Comment: @NathanJolly: Indeed, if I do need to swap it over rather than testing in parallel, those will make it much simpler.  Thanks!